# How to skip DateTime conversion?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

in VB.NET I have TextBox with masked time input such as

```
__:__
```

Before I save this to SQL database I have a conversion to iso format like:

```
Dim MyTime As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtMyTime.Text, "HH:mm", Nothing)
Dim isoMyTime As String = MyTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

Now my question is how to write to database Null value if this text box is empty without time value input?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you are stuck on SQL, or to figure out wether the textbox has been given a value.

when you write to database, you define the columns that you want to write to:

```
insert into Table1(Forename, Surname)
values(John, Jehnson)
```

if you want the surname to be null, simply do not mention it:

```
insert into Table1(Forename)
values(John)
```

Make sure your column is designed to allow nulls.

to figure out if the textbox has a value, simply Check if the values matches a actual valid format

**solution 1**

you can achieve this with a Regex:

```
[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

this regex makes sure that there are 2 numbers before and after the : sign.

**solution 2**

You can also replace the textbox with 2 numericupdown controls.

**solution 3**

another option is to try to parse it manually.

```
dim ISvalid as boolean = true
if textbox1.contains(":")
    if split(textbox1, ":").count = 2
        if split(textbox1, ":").first.length = 2 andalso split(textbox1, ":").last.length = 2
            if IsNumeric(split(textbox1, ":").first) andalso isnumeric(split(textbox1, ":").last
                ' this is a valid value
            else
                isvalid = false
            end if
        else
            isvalid = false
        end if
    else
        isvalid = false
    end if
else
    isvalid = false
end if

if isvalid then
    Dim MyTime As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtMyTime.Text, "HH:mm", Nothing)
    Dim isoMyTime As String = MyTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
end if
```